# One mouse click, two separate and simultaneous events

Tags: keyboard, multiple-monitors, mouse, synergy, presentations

Two laptops (both running same OSX). I want to click one thing (it can be a mouse button, or it can be a key, It doesn't matter), and have both computers recognize it. This would mean (if it was the keyboard example) if they both had a text editor up, and I hit 'a', then an 'a' would appear on both computers screens. If it was a mouse click, they both would at least register the click (doesn't have to mirror the mouse, just the click event).

I am trying to advance two separate presentations at the same time (a master and an accessory slide) going to two different video outputs, but they are for the same presentation. Basically I want to talk about an idea on the left, and show a picture on the right screen, but only click/press once and have both advance.

I have synergy running, and MouseShare, and CloneKeys, if that helps....

Another term that may be of help that I came across when researched: multibox(ing)

I do not have infrared sensors natively on either of the `MBPr`s I am using...

Comment: At a company I once worked for we could do this with an IR presentation "clicker" (the handheld device was also a laser pointer).  Basically the devices were not paired, meaning you could plug a separate  receiver into each computer and the hand held "clicker" would then advance both.  Unfortunately I can't find it in google at the moment.  A few years ago it was old technology.  The fact the devices were not paired is what made it work.

Comment: Actually this might be the device I just mentioned http://m.sears.com/ce-compass-usb-wireless-presentation-laser-pointer-powerpoint/p-SPM6447831608?hlSellerId=24513&sid=IDx20110310x00001i&kpid=SPM6447831608&kispla=SPM6447831608